# Solr reindex using Python

Tags: python, solr, database-management

I am planning to use Solr as a quasi-database to provide fast search functionality for text data. The maximum expected number of records is around 1 million, ~50 KB each.
Additionally, a relatively large number of user-defined custom fields are expected, necessitating frequent reindexing.

Of course, one cannot simply run something like:

```
response = solr.search(q="*:*")
solr.delete(q="*:*")
solr.commit()

all_data = [doc for doc in response]
for doc in all_data:
    solr.add(doc)
```

This raises the question: what are common reindexing strategies using Python, and how much time would they take to execute given the aforementioned data volume?
Can I create a new core with the same schema, and delete the old core?

Comment: Send the document to Solr when it changes, or do what you're saying - issue a delete, submit the new core, then commit - the old documents can still be searched until you commit. But generally, if you can limit the number of documents submitted to just be when they change, that's best. You can also index to a separate collection if you're using solrcloud, and then use a collection alias you can swap around from the old collection to the new one. If not using cloud mode, you can use the SWAP command in the CoreAdmin API after reindexing your whole set of documents.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for the quick answer. If I understood the whole process correctly, I should create some "swap_core", copy the actual schema to it, delete all index there (if there is any), commit and optimize, then copy all the data from the main_core to the swap_core and do the SWAP command between them?
And one more question about backup: since i have no "regular" RDBMS, can I create backups using localhost:8983/solr/<core_name>/replication?command=backup each N hours and will it be enough?

Comment: No need to copy all the previous data, just create a new core with the same configuration as the old one, then index to the new core, and issue a SWAP when you're done. When it comes to backups, that depends on what the source of your data is - it's highly recommended to have your primary data store somewhere other than Solr, since indexing is/can be a lossy process. If you're going to reindex having the data available somewhere else usually a good idea.

Comment: @MatsLindh And here I am again. I try to copy the core's configuration with creating a backup:
`response = requests.get(f"{solr_base_url}/replication?command=backup&name={backup_name}")`
And then loading it to another core:
`response = requests.get(f"{swap_core_url}/replication?command=RESTORE&location={backup_location}")`
I get 200 status code from both commands, but the "swap_core" is as empty as before.
How should I correctly load the created backup?

Comment: If you have a new question with a different subject, create a new question so that it's searchable later; I'm not very familiar with the backup API either, but you'll probably want to start by looking at the server log to see what happens - and whether the backup being taken is empty or not. These are usually also async operations, so the operation might not be finished when you receive the response; check the documentation

Comment: @MatsLindh so generally I am able to load the backup to another core?